# Getting row counts with specific conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get row counts based on different conditions with the below query but am not getting desired results.
Below are the conditions am trying to achieve

- Total number of tickets created for the day.
- Total number of tickets older than 10 days for that particular day
- Total number of open tickets .

Below is the query I wrote but the rows are getting multiplied

Below is the expected output

```
Date    No Ticket Created   > 10 Days   Total Open
9/12/2020   18                  12         25
9/13/2020   17                  14         25
9/14/2020   45                  14         31

SELECT
DISTINCT
CAST(A.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) [Date], 
[No Of Tickets Created] = (select count(*) from [AllTickets] B where OwnedByTeam='XYZ' AND cast(B.CreatedDateTime as date) = cast(A.CreatedDateTime as date)),
[> 10 Days] = (select count(*) from [AllTickets] B where OwnedByTeam='XYZ' AND B.CreatedDateTime <= (A.CreatedDateTime - 10) AND B.Status in('In Progress','New')),
[Total Open] = (select count(*) from [AllTickets] B where OwnedByTeam='XYZ' AND B.Status in('In Progress','New') and B.CreatedDateTime <= A.CreatedDateTime)
FROM 
[AllTickets] A
where OwnedByTeam='XYZ' AND 
A.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN GETDATE() - 3  AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY 
A.CreatedDateTime
ORDER BY 
DATE DESC
```

Comment: provide some sample data of your table

Comment: @Tulsi . . . Your data makes no sense.  You have only one date/time columns, so it is entirely unclear how you know how long a ticket is open.  Sample data is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I'd rather user CTE, it makes the query easier to write, read and modify later. here is the sample you can modify :

```
with cte_TotalOpenTicketsCount as
(
    select CAST(A.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) [Date], Count(*) FROM [AllTickets] WHERE ....
)
, cte_OlderThanTenDaysTicketCount AS
(
    select CAST(A.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) [Date], Count(*) FROM [AllTickets] WHERE ....
)
, cte_DailyTicketCount as 
(
    select CAST(A.CreatedDateTime AS DATE) [Date], Count(*) FROM [AllTickets] WHERE ....
)
select * from cte_DailyTicketCount as c1
LEFT join cte_OlderThanTenDaysTicketCount as c2 on c1.date = c2.Date
LEFT join cte_TotalOpenTicketsCount as c3 ON c2.Date = c3.Date
```